How do I get my object with a toon shader to have cast shadow's on it behave like it's shader?
When my object with a toon shader is in the cast shadow of another object the shadow is fuzzy. I want the cast shadow to be there, but have it follow the rules of the toon shader so its a hard shadow.
Checking off Render > Sampling > Shadows for either object just removes the drop shadow, same if I uncheck Object > Visibility > Shadow on the shadow cast object.


Wow, I think you have found another issue with eevee next.
I had issues with translucency and material blending i posted here:
https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/wEN1/
I replicated your issue then opened the same file with 4.0.2 and it auto-solved it.

My solution is to not use Eevee Next and stick to Legacy Eevee.
Even if you solve this shadow problem you are bound to have more issues.
I'll only consider using Next when it can match the legacy renders exactly without having to fix it.
Sorry for the bad news, i hope they find a way because next has great raytracing and displacement capabilities.
edit:
The workaround that Markus posted is really good and might do the trick for you. But it still renders the edge differently as shown:


Since your answer is more elaborate, I removed mine. You might want to remove the reference to my post to not confuse future visitors.

I think your solution is equally elaborate. I'll remove it if you insist but you found the best approximation using the current version. My solution may be a non starter if they require the latest features. In any case, thanks. you taught me something.
